# Are there differences for the Shapiro tests in Python and R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, python, shapiro-wilk-test

I am aiming to reproduce the issue (using Python) described in the answer here [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)

It states that the assumption of normality is more likely to be violated when the sample size of the studied distribution is large (n>1000) and the Shapiro-Wilk test for normality will become more sensitive to outliers. In other words, the Shapiro-Wilk test will more often extract the p-value as < 0.05 (rejecting the null hypothesis for normality of the distribution) on repetitive simulations of almost normally distributed data.

However, when I tried with Python implementation, there is almost never p<0.05 independently of the sample size I used to generate the distribution. I checked the implementation of the Shapiro-Wilk test both in Python (scipy.stats) and R (stats package) and they use the same algorithm from the paper ALGORITHM AS R94 APPL. STATIST. (1995) VOL. 44, NO. 4.

Why do I not obtain similar results with scipy? I attach my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

distributions = []

for _ in range(100):
    tmp_dist =[shapiro(np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 10), [1, 0, 2, 0, 1])))[1],
                shapiro(np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 100), [1, 0, 2, 0, 1])))[1],
                shapiro(np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000), [1, 0, 2, 0, 1])))[1],
                shapiro(np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 5000), [1, 0, 2, 0, 1])))[1],
                shapiro(np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 20000), [1, 0, 2, 0, 1])))[1]]
    distributions.append(tmp_dist)

df = pd.DataFrame(distributions, columns = ['n10','n100','n1000', 'n5000', 'n20000'])
```

Comment: There was some disagreement about the assertions you reference.  See the comment thread beginning with my comment at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless#comment143402_2498.  Please note that if by "almost Normally distributed data" you mean a data generation process that isn't Normal, then *of course* as the sample size grows any decent test will tend to yield small p-values. But your code seems to test only the null distribution, so it *ought* to generate $p\lt 0.05$ only 5% of the time. What, then, is wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the link and the comment. So the additional data I concatenate with the normal distribution [1, 0, 2, 0, 1] falls within parameters of the defined normal distribution, therefore shapiro-wilk test for the normality will not be affected, do I understand it right?

Comment: The basic ideas are (1) when you generate independent data with a truly Normal distribution, a correct implementation of a Normality test ought to yield a uniform distribution of p-values between $0$ and $1$ (except for small sample sizes) and (2) when you generate data in any other way, as the sample size grows the p-value distribution should shift more and more towards zero. You appear to be checking (1) in Python whereas the thread you reference verifies (a special case of) (2).

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, it is very clear